# AWS EC2: Cannot reach port 80 or 443 (https) using letsencrypt and nginx via docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I want to use a docker-compose file to set up an nginx server using letsencrypt to enable https on my AWS EC 2 instance.

However port 80 and port 443 seem to be closed.

The application itself is running under port 5000 which can be [reached](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/), however without https being enabled.

**Edit**
Here is the (almost) full docker-compose.yml, where I only added the last section under "services" called `letsencrypt`. Omissions are marked as (`[...]`):

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
    external: false

networks:
  cocoannotator:
    external: false

services:
  webserver:
    image: jsbroks/coco-annotator:webserver-stable
    container_name: annotator_webclient
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    [...]
    depends_on:
      - database
      - workers
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  workers:
    container_name: annotator_workers
    image: jsbroks/coco-annotator:workers-stable
    [...]
    depends_on:
      - messageq
      - database
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  messageq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    container_name: annotator_message_q
    [...]
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0
    container_name: annotator_mongodb
    restart: always
    [...]
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  letsencrypt:
     image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
     container_name: letsencrypt
     network_mode: host
     restart: always
     ports:
         - 80:80
         - 443:443
     volumes:
         - ./config:/config
     environment:
         # Domain name
         - URL=my-website-name.com
         - TZ=America/New_York
         - PGID=1000
         - PUID=1000
         # Subdomains to encrypt
         - SUBDOMAINS=www,annotator
     cap_add:
         - NET_ADMIN
```

It generates a config file for nginx in the local folder `./config/nginx/site-confs/default`
The default config is doing nothing, so following the advice of the [author](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator), I overwrote the file like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my-website-name.com www.my-website-name.com;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name _;

        root /config/www;
        include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
                index index.html index.htm;
                include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name annotator.*;

        include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
                include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        }
        location /socket.io {
                include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/socket.io;
        }
}
```

The only line I edited in `docker-compose.yml` as well as `conf` was to add my own website name (`my-website-name.com`).
The conf file seems to expose `http://localhost:5000/` which is correct.

I'm not sure what I'm missing. I could not find any firewall etc.

```
>$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

[Here](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/wiki/Getting-Started#setting-up-lets-encrypt-and-nginx) are the instructions I tried to follow and [here](https://github.com/jsbroks/coco-annotator/issues/231) some more discussion.

**Update**:
Here is the output of `netstat -anp | grep -i listen`

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     147252   -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/237614275f32621bfd15c8687fca24c735e48daeffd655ee6fe00fad5ca5d9ca/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     12687    -                    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123417   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123421   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123422   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123423   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123424   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123425   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     123426   31697/systemd        /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     141776   -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/b943888c331bf79cd6c1e2f7171a5961dddbb9ae163cfa1f27d2e7b6d4662444/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     17631    -                    @irqbalance924.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     141767   -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/6422696dfae2f404290918b4afff5a9e65155ed1ec333bc0e72994b565e702d5/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     145693   -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/fb9846bebcc81350c98c47f2c15811526cca22c30a0945ae7c227f921a305cce/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16691    -                    /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16571    -                    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16645    -                    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16647    -                    /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16649    -                    /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16651    -                    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16653    -                    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     141079   -                    @/containerd-shim/moby/31e14e9fa86fef5166d10363c9a4dd136af9f67f8c0d6f4bf79ebac50a474452/shim.sock@
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12676    -                    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12690    -                    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12702    -                    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     43836    -                    /run/containerd/containerd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44186    -                    /var/run/docker.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     44343    -                    /var/run/docker/metrics.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     45208    -                    /var/run/docker/libnetwork/ef4bf6e21227.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     12891    -                    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
```

Comment: Are you having problems accessing from the same machine or from outside AWS? If the latter, have you configured the instance security group to allow traffic?

Comment: I can access port 5000 from both outside and inside. 
I cannot access port 80 nor 443 from outside or inside.

Comment: So, "yes" the machine is reachable from outside. And "yes" I have edited the security group to allow all traffic  from anywhere

Comment: OK; security group is always the first question to ask for someone having connectivity problems. I'm not familiar with the image you're using, so can't give specific pointers, but in general I would use `netstat -anp | grep -i listen` on the host to verify that Docker is listening to the ports, and if yes exec into the container to look at the nginx logs.

Comment: I added the output of netstat above. Maybe the individual services in the docker-compose file cannot talk to each other? But I'm not sure how to check this? I could post the entire docker-compose.yml but it would probably not considere "minimal working example"

Comment: Well, it's showing that there's nothing listening on those ports as far as the host machine is concerned. I would exec into the nginx container and check out its logs.

Comment: Also why did you define port mapping ```ports: - 80:80 - 443:443```  if you have defined host network on lets encrypt container?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this running locally by adding an external network, and adding the letsencrypt (now SWAG) to both that external network and the cocoannotator network and removing `network_mode: "host"` (which I believe means it uses the default "bridge"?)

Contents of docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
volumes:
  mongodb_data:
    external: false

networks:
  cocoannotator:
    external: false
  external_net:
    external: true

services:
  letsencrypt:
    image: linuxserver/swag
    container_name: letsencrypt
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ./config:/config
    environment:
        # Domain name
        - URL=domain.com
        - TZ=Europe/London
        - PGID=1000
        - PUID=1000
        # Subdomains to encrypt
    cap_add:
        - NET_ADMIN
    networks:
      - external_net
      - cocoannotator

  webserver:
    image: jsbroks/coco-annotator:webserver-stable
    container_name: annotator_webclient
    restart: always
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=RandomSecretKeyHere
      - FILE_WATCHER=true
      - ALLOW_REGISTRATION=false
    volumes:
      - "./datasets:/datasets"
      - "./models:/models"
    depends_on:
      - database
      - workers
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  workers:
    container_name: annotator_workers
    image: jsbroks/coco-annotator:workers-stable
    volumes:
      - "./datasets:/datasets"
    depends_on:
      - messageq
      - database
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  messageq:
    image: rabbitmq:3
    container_name: annotator_message_q
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=user
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=password
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
  database:
    image: mongo:4.0
    container_name: annotator_mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
    volumes:
      - "mongodb_data:/data/db"
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --logpath=/dev/null"
    networks:
      - cocoannotator
```

And here is config\nginx\site-confs\default:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain.com;

        include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

        location / {
                include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
                proxy_pass http://webserver:5000/;
        }
        location /socket.io {
                include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
                proxy_pass http://webserver:5000/socket.io;
        }
}
```

Adding the letsencrypt service to the cocoannotator network lets you use "webserver" as the hostname, as technically it isn't "localhost".